# lex yacc nonterminal circularity

Tags: yacc, lex, circular-dependency

I have to implement a computer for string operations using YACC.I have to implement operations like +(for concatenating string) or *(to strcat a string with itself n times).These operations return a string and I use them in a nonterminal t1.BUt I also have operations that return a number.These operations are in a t2 nonterminal.

For example i have:

```
      expr1: expr1 '+' expr1 { strcpy($$,$1); strcat($$,$3);}
       | expr1 '-' expr1 { strcpy($$,minus($1,$3));}    
           | | expr1 '*' NUMBER {strcpy($$,mul($1,$3));}
           |STRING;
```

And i have:

```
     expr2 : STRING '?' STRING {strcpy($$nr_of_aparitions($1,$3));}
 ;
```

The thing is that the operations defined in expr2 will always return a NUMBER.
All works fine until:

if I have 'dfdf' ? 'edfd " for example it all works fine.The problem comes when i must implement expr1 in expr2 : expr1 ? expr2 because circularity would appear.Can you suggest anything ?

Comment: Have you also thought about operator precedence and associativity. For example, what does `expr1 - expr2 + expr3` mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you don't need to be concerned about what you call "circularity" and what I would call "recursion," that is, the use of a number-valued expression in expr1 and vice versa.

I would rewrite your grammar fragments as follows, to make your code easier to understand:

```
stringExpr : stringExpr '+' stringExpr { strcpy($$,$1); strcat($$,$3); }
           | stringExpr '-' stringExpr { strcpy($$,minus($1,$3)); }    
           | stringExpr '*' numberExpr { strcpy($$,mul($1,$3)); }
           | STRING
           ;

numberExpr : stringExpr '?' stringExpr { strcpy($$nr_of_aparitions($1,$3)); }
           | NUMBER
           ;
```

(I removed the empty rule in your expr1 -- I suppose that was not intended.)

I wonder why you don't have grammar rules for ordinary arithmetic, expressions like `5 + 2`, but perhaps that is not part of your plan.

If you do intend to support ordinary arithmetic, then you will need to think about how `"foobar" - 1 + 1` should be interpreted.  At that point, you may want to look at the yacc/bison features for [operator precedence](http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Precedence-Decl.html#Precedence-Decl).